# What is Dim in k-means clustering or K-medoids?

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means

> The Image contain clusters[K-mdoids clustering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDKFJ.jpg)

> Here is data that are used to make clusters.
> [Data that are used for clustering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5V7M.png)

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the images I'd guess there was a [Principal Component Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) (PCA) done before clustering. Otherwise your 8 dimensional space couldn't be plotted. The percent values are the percentage of variance explained by the principal component.

Comment: thanks so much Paul for you valueable feedback kindly tell me What is PCA?

Comment: I've edited the link in. Its a very common technique for dimensionality reduction and part of almost any data analysis course